# Express API - select one id from database

Tags: api, express, model-view-controller

i want to know how can i realize passing parameter to Model. I have 3 file server.js , controllers/news.js and models/news.js

Server.js

```
        const newsController = require('./controllers/news');

        server.get('/newsAll', newsController.all);

        server.post('/getOneNews', (req, res) => {
         db.get().query(`SELECT * FROM news WHERE id = ?`, [ req.body.id ], 
          (err, result, fields) => {
            if (err) console.log('error SELECT one row', err);
         });
        });
```

controller/news.js

```
const newsModule = require('../models/news');

 exports.all = (req, res) => {
  newsModule.all((err, rows) => {
    if (err) {
        console.error(err);
        return res.sendStatus(500);
    }
    res.send(rows);
   });
  };
```

models/news.js

```
const db = require('../db');

 exports.all = (done) => {
  db.get().query(`SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY id`, (err, rows) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log('error SELECT * FROM news MYSQL', err);
        throw err;
    }
    done(err, rows);
   });
 };
```

All about method all i understood , but i want to know how can i passing [ req.body.id ] (<- from front-end) this parametr to Model for accepting ONE news from database . Whithout parameters it is very easy.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to do is grab the id from the `req.params` object and then set your endpoint to accept that params value.

```
// Server.js

server.get('/getOneNews/:id', (req, res) => {
  db.get().query(`SELECT * FROM news WHERE id = ?`, [ req.params.id ], 
      (err, result, fields) => {
        if (err) console.log('error SELECT one row', err);
   });
});
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes, thanx , all right, but iwant to realize this with model view and controller NOT all in one file.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by model view?

Comment: MVC pattern , i want to do this NOT in one file , look like a method.all ,